# How to delete a newly created SQL server database backup file in c#?

Tags: c#, delete-file, database-backups

I'm creating a desktop application that backs up SQL server database periodically and sends the backup as attachment over email. After every iteration, I modify the file name to look like Backup, Backup_1, Backup_2 etc., to identify the files at the receiving end.

In the scenario where creating backup is successful (say Backup_1), but sending email has failed, I would like to delete the backup (Backup_1), so that I can reuse the same name in next iteration. In this way there would not be any gaps in the receiving end.

Unfortunately, when I delete the backup file, I'm getting the exception: "The process cannot access the file 'D:\Backups\Backup_1.bak' because it is being used by another process." I'm not aware of any other process that can access this file.

Please advise on how to tackle this issue.

I tried running as administrator, closing SQL Server Management Studio, but nothing helped.
How do I find the process that's blocking me?

Comment: What happens when the SMTP server receives the e-mail (not failed at that point) but it never gets delivered (failed outside of your ability to detect it)? How do you expect to reuse a number then? Is it worth it to avoid gaps? Do you also try reuse numbers in `IDENTITY` columns when a row get deleted or an insert in a transaction gets rolled back? Just trying to get you to think critically about the value of the effort involved in avoiding gaps.

Comment: E-mail is an insecure way to transmit your data. If you don't care who possesses your data, then it may not be an issue. Are you performing full backups or incremental backups?

Comment: @madreflection:Thanks for the input. I think I can live with the missing backups in between. But for the base backup at least, I would need some mechanism. Maybe in that case,  I can give a different name altogether instead of deleting.

Comment: @user09938: Security is not much of an issue for my use case. My first backup is full, and the later ones differential.

Comment: The following may be of interest [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon)

Comment: Many e-mail servers have a maximum size for an attachment. The max size could be less than 10 MB. Have you considered a cloud storage solution such as [OneDrive Business](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/onedrive/onedrive-for-business)?

Comment: @user09938: Mine is a database that has minimal content which I'm expecting to be within the permissible limits of email attachment. Maybe in the next stages we can think of cloud storage solutions. Thanks for bringing that though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it was the email sending part, that was holding reference to the attachment. Disposing the email attachments in both successful and failure scenarios did the trick.
Also, I moved away from this approach to sending backups as json attachments and adding in server database as it gave me more flexibility.